# PHP to Jquery submit request

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new with this and i don't know how to implement this PHP script into jQuery to submit my form and output the accept and decline message. Can someone help me with this?

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['file']) && !empty($_POST['file']))
{    
$mp3file= new MP3File($_FILES['file']['name']);
$duration = $mp3file->getDuration();

 $time_limit = "02:10"; // Time limit

 $accepted = "Your music has: ".MP3File::formatTime($duration)." seconds.</br> And is accepted by our terms ";
 $declined = "Your music has: ".MP3File::formatTime($duration)." seconds and is not accepted by our terms"; 

if(MP3File::formatTime($duration) <= $time_limit) 
{
$audio=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$audio=str_replace(' ','',$audio);
$tmppath1="music/".$audio;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$tmppath1);

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", ""); 
$save=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO music (location, userid) VALUES ('$tmppath1','1')");
echo $accepted;

} else {
  echo $declined;
}
 } 
?>
```

HTML FORM:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" name="upload">  
<div class="bs-example">
<label class="btn-bs-file btn btn-success">SELECT MUSIC</label>
<input id="input-1a" type="file" class="file" name="file" data-provides="file">

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-bs-file btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="SUBMIT MUSIC"></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Update improved:

JQUERY Script based @Jude Fernandes response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
    $("#upload").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var form_data = new FormData();
         form_data.append('file', $('#input-1a').prop('files'));

          $.ajax({
            url: "upload-music.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: To submit using jQuery you do `$("#upload").submit();`

Comment: Yes, but i don't know to output accepted and decline message

Comment: in your php code you have to return an array `{success:true, message:'My accepted/declined message'}`  or however you want to structure the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @altoids, can you help me with an example? I'm new and i don't know how exactly to do that..

Comment: 1. Post your jquery in your original post. 2. replace `echo $accepted` with `return $accepted`. Same thing with `echo $declined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" name="upload">
    <div class="bs-example">
        <label class="btn-bs-file btn btn-success">SELECT MUSIC</label>
        <input id="input-1a" type="file" class="file" name="file" data-provides="file">

        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn-bs-file btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="SUBMIT MUSIC"></button>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
    $("#upload").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var form_data = new FormData();
         form_data.append('key_file', $('#input-1a').prop('files')[0]);

          $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com/foo.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

            },
            error: function () {
               // Handle an error in the connection
            }
        });

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what the front end file should looks like, I have made a few modifications to the form ie, the button is of type submit so jquery catches the event when you press submit.

The line `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default action of the form which is to submit the form and reload the page, instead jquery processes the request and submits it.

The `var form_data = new FormData();` is a convenient helper where you can add all the parameters that you want to send to the backend in the format `form_data.append('key', 'value');`

A slight modification in the backend, you can replace the line `if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")` with `if (isset($_POST['key_file']) && !empty($_POST['key_file']))` the `key_file` is what you are sending from the front end so you need to check if that key is set and it exists.

`$("#upload").submit(function (e)` specifies that jquery needs to catch the submit event of a form with an `id=upload`.

P.S. Open inspect element on your browser and goto the networks tab and monitor the params being sent and the response coming back, it will help you alot

Comment: I have done as you mentioned, but in the console i have nothing, i have modified the isset as you told me to do.

Comment: Do you have an error in your console? There's no request being made in the networks tab under XHR?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no i don't, only : XHR finished loading: POST

Comment: I have changed the prop files [0] to files and now i get: b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file

Comment: When you say XHR finished loading: POST do you mean some other request completed or your request completed?

Comment: My request , but nothing in return, i have updated my question, and with that changes now i got: filename cannot be empty.

Comment: Click on your request, so it opens up its details, scroll down and check the params that are sent, most probably you'll have to reset the file thing that you changed back to files [0], once you do that you should see the file being sent in the params.Once that is complete, completely remove your backend code and replace it with json_encode("test"); If you get a response back then there's some problem in the backend code that you are running and not the ajax request.

Comment: Done, in the back end i have changed  _POST to _FILES and now is return me the accepted and decline message. and file is beign uploaded.

Comment: Ah yes i think i missed that,np.

Comment: No problem Bro. Many Thanks!